# jquery: select a Select option by value

Tags: jquery

I have the following (=>) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radi8/kjdwF/). What it does is search for a Select Option by value and then set the attribute of the found option as selected. Pretty simple. This script (replicated below) works fine in IE 9 and FireFox 17, but not in Chrome OR Safari. These 2 browsers fail to set the attribute as selected.

Am I missing something here?

**EDIT: it looks like I needed to use .prop() rather than .attr().**

The Select HTML:

```
<select id="listmcu">
    <option value="1002">PA</option>
    <option value="1003">CA</option>
    <option value="1004">OR</option>
    <option value="1005">FL</option>
    <option value="1006">TX</option>
</select>
```

The JQuery;

```
$(function () {
    var mcu = "1005";
     alert ('Begin: mcu val = ' + mcu);
    //$("#listmcu").find("option:contains('" + mcu + "')").each(function () {
    $("#listmcu").find("option[value='" + mcu + "']").each(function () {
        alert ('In contains: this val = ' + $(this).val());
        if ($(this).val() == mcu) {
            //$(this).attr("selected", "selected");
            $(this).prop("selected", "selected"); // <== appears to work
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `selected` is a property, not an attribute. You should be using `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use this to resolve your issue:

```
$(this).prop("selected", true);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kjdwF/2/)

Comment: Another "DOH" moment for me. Thanks for the help, I knew it had to be a simple issue. I must have RTFM several times on .attr() but <ahem> missed the part about the .prop() for properties. Thanks again to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too hard on yourself. Just use [.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on the select box and let jQuery do the heavy lifting:

```
$(function () {
    var mcu = "1005";
     alert ('Begin: mcu val = ' + mcu);
    $("#listmcu").val(mcu);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QsbXT/)